# How to Resume/Interrupt BackgroundWorker Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

In my program, there will be a time where I have to call

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

to "temporarily pause" the BackgroundWorker. A groupbox will be shown before the backgroundworker thread sleeps. That groupbox has a button that should "wake up" the backgroundworker thread and continue it.

If I call Thread.Interrupt() (which by the way I can't seem to use unless I create a Thread object, which I shouldn't do) at the button_Click event, like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Interrupt(); //interrupt thread
    }
```

The Thread it "would" interrupt is the UI Thread, am I right? What I need to do is to Interrupt the BackgroundWorker thread. How do I do this?

EDIT: Thanks for those that replied to this question. I'll use AutoResetEvent. Seems more appropriate for my use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with the high-level concept:

What you should do is have a token that you check every so often in the code that is being executed by the BackgroundWorker. When the token is set your background code will stop the normal flow and just check the token every now and then and when the token is cleared the background code can continue processing.

So the interesting part above is the token. What I would do is maybe have a boolean that I check and when that boolean is set to `true` I would block the thread by waiting on `ManualResetEvent`. When you want to resume the processing you set the boolean to false and use the `Set()` method of the ManualResetEvent to release allow the code to continue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I should use this ManualResetEvent instead on the Thread.Sleep();?

Comment: Yes - where you call Thread.Sleep in your example replace it with a call to WaitOne on your ManualResetEvent. Then in the button handler call Set on the ManualResetEvent to release the thread. You might also want to consider whether an AutoResetEvent suits your needs better (i.e., it automatically resets to the non-signalled state when the waiting thread has been released)

Comment: The Semaphore NirMH posted really helped. What is the difference of that to ManualResetEvent? Seems like they were used the same. And which is better in this case?

Comment: I think AutoResetEvent really does suit my needs better :) Thanks :)

Comment: Think of the ManualResetEvent as a gate and any thread wanting to pass through it must call WaitOne on it.  When it's open (after a call to Set) any thread can pass through it, when it's closed (after a call to Reset) the threads will wait until it's opened. (The constructor parameter indicates it's initial state).  A semaphore is more like a gate with a bouncer controlling it (closing it when it meets capacity and not opening it again until a thread leaves - after calling Release).

Comment: @Gerald Torres, I would definitely suggest that you use the Manual or AutoResetEvent. The Semaphore is better suited to scenarios that require you to restrict the number of concurrent threads that have access to a resource. In your case you simply need a way to signal the thread that it can continue working, which is a common use for Manual/AutoResetEvent. Btw. In your case I do agree AutoResetEvent will probably work better.

Comment: And AutoResetEvent is like a gate like ManualResetEvent that automatically closes (no need to Reset), which is definitely what I should use. Thanks, IanR and Chris Taylor.

Answer (score 2):

You have to look at [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)

Usage:

```
ManualResetEvent e = new ManualResetEvent(false);  //global variable
e.WaitOne(); // Thread will wait until event is triggered
e.Set(); // Trigger event from other thread
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a semaphore to sync between the threads.

once you want the background worker to "sleep", grap a handle on the semaphore, once you click on the "wake up" button, release the semaphore and the background worker will resume..

From your GUI thread (the one that shows the button) your should declare

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0, 1);
```

on the background worker thread - this statement initialize a semaphore with a default value of 0 (locked)

on your backgroundworker thread/code call:

```
s.WaitOne();
```

this statement actually cause the background worker to wait until the semaphore is released by the gui thread (your wake up button).

on the button click handler, call the:

```
s.Release();
```

the release operation allows the background worker code to resume running.

Comment: THANKS! Exactly what I need! Easy to use also!